# Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 sp1 web pages look like the browser is in Mobile mode

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11, homepage, mobile-ui

Lately when I'm online (Windows 7, IE 11) the browser has really large margins, as if it is in Mobile mode. I tried to scroll to the bottom of my Yahoo homepage and it just kept going and going. Originally, I was curious why my homepage had the same stories that I saw yesterday. I have had a lot of wifi security concerns lately. Did I just somehow switch from "desktop" to Mobile? I don't believe that is the case. How can I get it back to my normal homepage?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Can you please specify what have you done to trigger such behavior (ex. settings you've changed)? Also specify the version of Windows and your computer characteristics.

Comment: reset internet options to default and post results